# Concept: Comparing objects and arrays like atrings and numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, comparison, object-comparison

**Is there a way to compare two un-referenced objects by their literal value like a string or a number?**

`_is = function (a, b) { /* Code */ }`

This could apply to any object type, even custom objects.

`_is(new X("a"), new X("a")); // Returns True;`

`_is(new X("a"), new Y("a")); // Returns False`

You could convert it into a string, but that would be sloppy.

`JSON.stringify({ x: "a" }) == JSON.stringify({ x: "a" }); // Returns True`

Maybe there's a way to programatically read each key, subkey, and value of the object, and compare that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Javascript compares objects by reference.

Comment: @SLaks what does that mean? How do I get around this?

Comment: Two distinct objects are **never** `==` (or `===`) to eachother. You are of course free to create your own function(s) to compare objects for whatever "equality" means for your application.

Comment: @Maxwill Ever hear of pointers in C or C++? an object reference is simply a pointer to where the object is stored in memory. When you say `if(obj1 === obj2)` you are asking if they are referencing the same memory location.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the question to better fit my intent

Comment: @Maxwill Try this out: https://repl.it/H09J/1

Comment: @Maxwill Thanks, now the duplicate fits even better

Comment: @Bergi Can this question be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript hashes objects in memory with unique memory pointers. You're essentially creating two separate objects, and trying to compare them. Despite the fact that they *look* similar, they in fact are different.

Try storing the object as a variable first, and then testing against that variable.

```js
pass = arg => { return arg }; pass({ a: "x" }); // Returns The Input

pass(({ a: "x" })) == ({ a: "x" }); // Returns False

var obj = {a: "x"};

pass(obj) === (obj); // Returns true

console.log(pass(obj) === (obj));
```

UPDATE:

If you want to compare two separate objects, the best and most efficient way I've found is to create a hash of both objects, and then compare the hashes (basically comparing two checksums). If the hashes match, the objects are the same. If the hashes differ, they are different objects. You can assume that the properties and values are the same in each object, since using a hashing function, even hashing functions used in some forms of crypto like md5 and sha can be utilized to generate a unique hash of the object.

[Here's a 3rd Party Library I've used before to generate object hashes](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash).

Comment: Alright, it worked.

Comment: Still, It would be cool if there was a way to allow this.

Comment: Yeah, it's by creating a variable and using that, since it ensures you are using the same object reference.

Comment: Please mark correct if it's correct :)

Comment: it's "correct" but not what I was looking for. Thanks though

Comment: Please mark it correct if it's correct so that others who may stumble upon this question will know the solution is resolved. You cannot achieve what you're asking for any other way. Not sure what else you're "looking for."

Comment: Alright. I set it as the correct answer but it's still not really the answer. I was asking if you could compare literal objects, not how to avoid it as if it were a "mistake"

Comment: Ah, I see you've edited your original post quite a bit, sorry about that. My recommendation would be to use a hash function to hash both objects and then compare the hashes. https://github.com/puleos/object-hash

You could also try to stringify the entire object, strip out all whitespace and generate a checksum for each of the objects. If the checksums match, they are the same object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142663/discussion-between-maxwill-and-danny-bullis).